# Server can't file_get_contents on https

Tags: php, https, file-get-contents

I'm trying to get my FB app access token using the following code:

```
$app_token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
. "client_id=" . $app_id
. "&client_secret=" . $app_secret 
. "&grant_type=client_credentials";
$response = file_get_contents($app_token_url);
$params = null;
parse_str($response, $params);

echo("This app's access token is: " . $params['access_token']);
```

It works fine from `localhost` but not from my server (connection times out). The openssl library is enabled according to phpinfo().

Update: the problem seems to occur on any https URL. allow_url_fopen is On.

Update 2: it seems like it is a firewall issue. I can't wget any https url when I log on the server via SSH. I've asked them to open port 443.

Answer (score 2):

Try Check your openssl can wrapper data or not in your server?

code to check:

```
<?php
$check = stream_get_wrappers();
echo 'openssl: ',  extension_loaded  ('openssl') ? 'isload':'noload','<br>';
echo 'http: ', in_array('http', $check) ? 'ok':'no','<br>';
echo 'https: ', in_array('https', $check) ? 'ok':'no','<br>';
?>
```

if ok will get output:

```
openssl: isload
http: ok
https: ok
```

Comment: Thanks, I get this output exactly. Actually I just tried to perform a simple wget on my server via SSH and it turns out that I can't wget any https url. So apparently my host is just blocking port 443. I've asked them to open it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$url = 'https://www.google.com.eg';

function curl_get_contents($url){
  $ch = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $data;
}
echo curl_get_contents($url);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Please remember that a little explanation goes a long way when adding an answer.  The original asker is probably not going to get much from a code only answer and a new asker could get a lot more if you explained how your answer solves the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the timeout limit:

```
<?php 
$context = stream_context_create(array( 
    'http' => array( 
        'timeout' => 60 
        ) 
    ) 
); 
file_get_contents("http://example.com/", 0, $context); 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't work. Apparently the problem occurs with any https url (works fine with an http url)